# tensorflow using only one gpu when building gradients

Tags: tensorflow

I am running the following code:

```
tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss=loss)
```

however, the gpu usage is really on one gpu like following:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.66                 Driver Version: 384.66                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K40m          Off  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   34C    P0    63W / 235W |      0MiB / 11439MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla K40m          Off  | 00000000:03:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   33C    P0    64W / 235W |      0MiB / 11439MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Tesla K40m          Off  | 00000000:81:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   31C    P0    63W / 235W |      0MiB / 11439MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  Tesla K40m          Off  | 00000000:82:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   31C    P0    65W / 235W |      0MiB / 11439MiB |     95%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Is it by default that this particular function has to be in one single GPU?

What should I do to make is run on all gpus?

Comment: Do you read this tutorial: [Training a Model Using Multiple GPU Cards](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn#training_a_model_using_multiple_gpu_cards) ?

Comment: @Vladimir Bystricky Yeah, I read it. It said that after setting all the graphs we can use multi GPU to train the net and average it. But here I am facing a problem where the function tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss=loss) is in the process of building the graph.